# How to get a style using the console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a div

```
<div class="blue>;
```

The class blue is:

```
    .blue {
          background-color: blue;
    }
```

Now I know I can set the background color of the div in the console using:

```
      $0.style.backgroundColor = "#ffcc00"
```

But what if I want to get the value of the background color for that element using the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
var blue = document.getElementsByClassName('blue')[0];

blue.style.getPropertyCSSValue('background-color');
```

or you do:

```
blue.style.getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

Comment: i hope you noticed the console executes javascript and no special command syntax

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you may want computed style:

```
var style = getComputedStyle(document.body, null); // Gets the style for a passed element and optional pseudo selecter (eg. :hover)
console.log(style.backgroundColor);
```

It's important to note that computed style is the rendered result. If you have multiple rules for the same element, this will only display the ones that have been applied.